# Is there a way to downgrade mysqlbackup?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-backup

I have a client that backed up his data with MEB 4.0.0, so now I need to extract the contents of the image, but because I'm using mysql Enterprise Backup 8.0 I can't since it's not compatible.

Is there a way to downgrade my mysqlbackup? Or maybe upgrade his Image? Right now it's in .MBI so I don't see a way out of this since I can't extract and can't find the older version of the mysqlbackup anywhere.

I'm using Windows 10 btw, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you've got a license to use MySQL Enterprise Backup, then you must have a support contract with Oracle. Call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just found out, there is NO WAY do downgrade or get the installer officialy, but there is sites like archive.org that have the old installer there.

If anyone is having trouble because of this problem I suggest to look there.